# How do I check if delegate returns true inside of a method?

Tags: c#, methods, delegates

I am trying to solve a task from my exam but I'm having trouble with delegates. The task asks me to define a method for class FoodTraker which takes a delegate of type `Func<Portion,bool>` as an argument and deletes all portions from the list which satisfy the delegate criteria. Also in main test the code by giving an argument to the method which will filter all the portions whose price is greater than 30 per weight.

```
public class Portion
    {
        public Portion(decimal price, double weight, double kcal)
        {
            Price = price;
            Weight = weight;
            Kcal = kcal;
        }
    public decimal Price { get; private set; }
    public double Weight { get; private set; }
    public double Kcal { get; private set; }


    }





public class FoodTracker
    {
        public List<Portion> portions;

        public Func<Portion, bool> PortionDelegate;
        

        public FoodTracker()
        {
            portions = new List<Portion>();
        }
    public void Track(Portion portion)
        {
            portions.Add(portion);
        }

    public virtual Decimal CalculateProfit()
        {
            Decimal sum = 0;
            foreach(var portion in portions)
            {
                sum += portion.Price;
            }
            return sum;
        }

    public void PortionRemover(Func<Portion,bool> portionDelegate)
        {
           portions.Remove(portion);
        }
    }


public class Program
    {
        
        
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Portion portion1 = new Portion(10m, 500, 1000);
            Portion portion2 = new Portion(20m, 200, 200);
            Portion portion3 = new Portion(5m, 50, 500);
            Portion portion4 = new Portion(30m,1000, 700);
            NutritionalTracker tracker = new NutritionalTracker(699, 501);
            List<Portion> portions = new List<Portion>();
            tracker.Track(portion1);
            tracker.Track(portion2);
            tracker.Track(portion3);
            tracker.Track(portion4);
            portions.Add(portion1);
            portions.Add(portion2);
            portions.Add(portion3);
            portions.Add(portion4);
             
           
            



        Console.WriteLine(tracker.CalculateProfit());

        }
```

My first problem is that I don't know how to check the bool condition of the delegate inside the method which leads to me not being able to do the rest of the task.

Comment: `var result = portionDelegate.Invoke(portion);` or `var result = portionDelegate(portion);`

Comment: `portions.RemoveAll(portionDelegate);`? Not clear which function / line of code you actually want this.

Comment: @Andy I am not sure how that helps me maybe I'm just delusional or you didn't understand my question. Also Charlieface I never intend to use RemoveAll.
What I first did was 
`foreach(var portion in portions)
{
if(PortionDelegate == true)
{ portions.Remove(portion)}
}
`
but that obviously wasnt correct.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove like this

Add Linq extension functions on using block;

`using System.Linq;`

change your method for filter the list and set it.

```
public void PortionRemover(Func<Portion, bool> portionDelegate)
    {
        portions = portions.Where(portionDelegate).ToList();
    }
```

call example

```
 FoodTracker tracker = new FoodTracker();
 tracker.PortionRemover(p => p.Price > 30);
```

Comment: Even though I'm not doubting the correctness of the solution I think I am not allowed to use Linq in that task so a solution without using it would be preferable if possible.Also I need to filter them by the price/weight > 30.